# Anaconda3 Installation error

Tags: anaconda

I'm getting 'Installation Error' when installing Anaconda3 - no additional information. During the install, I get message 'Anaconda3 already installed - use conda update anaconda3.' So then I try conda and get:

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you behind a firewall or proxy of some kind?

Answer (score 0):

Did the screen show the following lines also?

```
An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
```

`HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
 SSLError(SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",),)`

If yes, then the error can be resolved if you can configure your SSL (using certificate if you have one)

In our university, Strong Firewall is enabled,that blocks many websites.
They provide certificate to be configured to conda.
We run the following command in terminal before installing anything new or updating conda:

```
conda config --set ssl_verify <location of the certificate.pem file>
```

This [link](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/6007) also has many ways to resolve the above issues

Comment: None, repeat None, of the solutions worked; here or on the linked page. I see this problem is widely encountered. Is this not the responsibility of the  writers of the software to offer guidance?